# Call Method in Activity on change between Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity `ActivityA`, and a fragment `FragOne`. I also have a button that replace `FragOne` to `FragTwo`.

I wanna call method in `ActivityA` when the fragment changes from `FragOne` to `FragTwo` or vice-versa.

In my problem, I want `FragOne` and `FragTwo` to be independent from `ActivityA`.

I think of something using life cycle from `Activity`.

Some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

I use this in activity:

```
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

From `Fragment` call `((ActivityA) getActivity()).yourMethod();`

Also, check if `getActivity() != null` before calling `yourMethod()`

Comment: In my problem, I wanna that FragOne and FragTwo to be independent from ActivityA.

Comment: I think of something using LifeCycle from Activity.

Comment: EVERY FRAGMENT Needs to be attached to an ACTIVITY, so use your fragment's onAttached() wisely. Using an interface is the best practice

Answer (score 2):

Create a interface class. Implement this interface in Activity class. Attach this interface in both fragments. In "Fragment A", on clicking button, call interface method.

In Activity, the overridden method will achieve the requires functionality(Switching fragment in this case).

You can achieve same vice versa, ie, calling activity method and getting into "Fragment A", from "Fragment B".

Comment: In my problem, I wanna that FragOne and FragTwo to be independent from ActivityA.

Comment: I think of something using LifeCycle from Activity.

Comment: Thats why there is concept of interfaces. It makes your fragment losely coupled.

Comment: Is there a way of not having to insert an interface on fragment?

Comment: As mentioned by @Carnel, follow that.